# undefined columns selected error message in R

Tags: r

I am very new to R and using a script someone else wrote.  Belows is part of the script where I am getting an error message:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(this.df.merged, c("MMWR_week", "Syndrome
>   Visits",  :    undefined columns selected

I looked up other repsonses to similar questions and couldn't really find my solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
if (!("other" %in% colnames(this.df.merged))) {
    this.df.merged$other<-0
}

this.df.merged.by_week<-aggregate(this.df.merged[c("Syndrome Visits","E","other","0-4","25-49","5-24","50-64","over 64","F","M","U","Admit","Disch")],by=list(this.df.merged$MMWR_week),sum)
colnames(this.df.merged.by_week)<-c("MMWR_week","Syndrome Visits","E","other","0-4","25-49","5-24","50-64","over 64","F","M","U","Admit","Disch")
write.csv(this.df.merged.by_week, file=paste(this.diseaseName,"_Count_Query_Summary_Table_by_Week_",this.beginDate,"_",this.endDate,".csv",sep=""))

return(this.df.merged)
```

}

Comment: pleasemakeyourcodemorereadable

Comment: Seems unlikely there would be a column names "Syndrome Visits" (with a space in it). What does `names(this.df.merged)`. When posting a question, please take the time to include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) because otherwise we have no idea what the structures of the objects you are working with are which makes it very difficult to help you.

Comment: Thanks Richard, still trying to get the hang of this.  Your suggestion seems to be correct, I don't think syndrome visits exists.  I will look into this more, thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `this.df.merged` may not contain one of the names in the vector `c("Syndrome Visits","E","other","0-4","25-49","5-24","50-64","over 64","F","M","U","Admit","Disch")`

I suggest checking that the names do exists and/or are spelled correctly in this.df.merged. Here is some sample code to check that the names exist. It is up to you to decide why they don't exist, which would have occurred somewhere else in your code before this point

```
if (!("other" %in% colnames(this.df.merged))) {
    this.df.merged$other<-0
}

namevector=c("Syndrome Visits","E","other","0-4","25-49","5-24","50-64","over 64","F","M","U","Admit","Disch")

n=colnames(this.df.merged)

tmp=sapply(namevector,function(x){
            if(!any(n==x)){
               print(paste(x,"not found"))
               return(TRUE)
            }
            return(FALSE)
           })
if(any(tmp))stop("some column names not found")


this.df.merged.by_week<-aggregate(this.df.merged[c("Syndrome Visits","E","other","0-4","25-49","5-24","50-64","over 64","F","M","U","Admit","Disch")],by=list(this.df.merged$MMWR_week),sum)
colnames(this.df.merged.by_week)<-c("MMWR_week","Syndrome Visits","E","other","0-4","25-49","5-24","50-64","over 64","F","M","U","Admit","Disch")
write.csv(this.df.merged.by_week,file=paste(this.diseaseName,"_Count_Query_Summary_Table_by_Week_",this.beginDate,"_",this.endDate,".csv",sep=""))

return(this.df.merged)
```

Comment: Thanks Oscar, you are right, the column for "Syndrome Visits" was never created for some reason.  The first column created was "E" and so on.  I will look into this.